# RecyclableMemoryStreamManager as Singleton

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, .net-core, garbage-collection

In a **.Net Core** **Web API** or **MVC** that needs to export lots of large Excel files which is the best way to improve Memory usage?

I'm currently using `RecyclableMemoryStream`s, however for what I've read on Ben Watson's [Post](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2015/02/06/announcing-microsoft-io-recycablememorystream/):

> Note that RecyclableMemoryStreamManager should be declared once and it will live for the entire process–this is the pool.

I understood that the best scenario for optimizing memory and GC collections is to have only one `RecyclableMemoryStreamManager` instance for the lifetime of my application life. So Should I use It as a **Singleton**?

When I do this, the memory pooling works just fine. But will the memory be deallocated in case of other parts of the system requiring it?

I've tested here and it increases the pool only when needed but I haven't noticed it decreasing...

Comment: Create a readonly static field initializing it with a RecyclableMemoryStreamManager  and you got your singleton. Freeing the array pool internally held by RecyclableMemoryStreamManager on demand is not possible as far as i am aware, however the code of RecyclableMemoryStreamManager is rather short and simple and it should be no problem to modify it and implement this feature by yourself. It essentially should boil down to just clearing the collections with the byte arrays in RecyclableMemoryStreamManager (plus probably doing an LOH compacting) if you need to.

Comment: @elgonzo yes, this a possible solution. however in this way, I would need to know the best time to clear the byte array collection based on memory pressure. Maybe I could implement this byte array as a WeakCollection (a collection of WeakReferences). This way I wouldn't need to manually clear the array. Correct?

Comment: WeakReferences are only of limited help, i guess. If the byte arrays are on the LOH (that is, their memory requirement is >= 85000 bytes), WeakReferences will not protect against possible LOH fragmentation (which could also lead to OutOfMemoryExceptions even if enough free memory seems to be available). If you use byte arrays smaller than 85000, you would not need RecyclableMemoryStream. But note, i only talk based on my knowledge about the .NET framework here. I don't know if the LOH behavior in .NET Core has changed or not in comparison to the .NET framework.

Comment: what did you end up doing in the end? Did a singleton work?